# How to stop the webservice call when we move to another view

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am doing one application.  In it, I did the web service part for each view.  So when I moved to another view without completion of present view we service, then I need to stop the web service call in the present view.

Please tell me how to do this. My sample code to start the service is given below:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
  request=[self GetRequest];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

.
.
.

Comment: Just make it's object "task" nil so it will release it when u move from one view to another. Also I don't see any good point of stopping task. Rather when user make a service call you could show a activity indicator and prevent user to jump from one view to another.

Comment: why did you put dots ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [task cancel];
}
```

and use `@property(nonatomic,retain)NSURLSessionTask *task;`